# Get First URL from Google

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this answer from another thread but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I have a list of companies in column A, and trying to get their URL addresses from Google.

The code errors out with message no object found at this line:

Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

```
Sub XMLHTTP()

    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")

        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("h3")


        For Each link In objH3

            If link.className = "r" Then

                Cells(i, 2) = link.innerText
                Cells(i, 3) = link.getelementsbytagname("a")(0).href
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time) & " :minutes"
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: [Doesn't seem to work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is no question. Please explain where you have an issue and what you expect instead.

Comment: sorry i have updated the question with the error message

Comment: Well, if you do the same search in your browser and check source, is there element with id "rso". My best bet is that there is not.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but the classes seem to be changing all the time.. Is there another workaround for this?